# What does ממנ”פ mean?

Tags: halacha, words, hebrew, acronyms

I've seen the acronym ממנ”פ in multiple places but I am not sure what it means.
[קיצורים וראשי תיבות בעברית](http://www.kizur.co.il/search_word.php) indicates that it means ממערכת נשימה פנימית but I am not sure if that is correct.

Here are some places when I have seen that acronym used:

1. https://www.hebrewbooks.org/rambam.aspx?mfid=8818&rid=4353
2. [https://he.wikisource.org/wiki/הגהות_רבי_עקיבא_איגר/אורח_חיים/סימן_קנג](https://he.wikisource.org/wiki/%D7%94%D7%92%D7%94%D7%95%D7%AA_%D7%A8%D7%91%D7%99_%D7%A2%D7%A7%D7%99%D7%91%D7%90_%D7%90%D7%99%D7%92%D7%A8/%D7%90%D7%95%D7%A8%D7%97_%D7%97%D7%99%D7%99%D7%9D/%D7%A1%D7%99%D7%9E%D7%9F_%D7%A7%D7%A0%D7%92)
3. https://images.shulcloud.com/419/uploads/Yadrim/Yadrim3.pdf

Comment: https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/581/mi-yodeya-glossary/2304#2304

Comment: Asher Ross, [Welcome to Mi Yodeya](//judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/a/3887), and thanks very much for the well written question! I appreciate the time you took to include examples and a description which helped us quickly get you the answer you sought. Looking forward to seeing you around

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Seemingly this stands for [ממה נפשך](https://hebrew-academy.org.il/2015/12/21/%D7%9E%D7%9E%D7%94-%D7%A0%D7%A4%D7%A9%D7%9A/) which literally means something like "what[ever] you want" but roughly translates to "either way" and is a technical term used to introduce a logical argument of [disjunction elimination](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Disjunction_elimination).